# devstack error:deprecated has no attribute NEWTON

Tags: openstack, devstack

when i tried to install devstack on Ubuntu 14.04,the error occurred. 
[stage/main/keystone]error:versionutuils deprecated has no attribute NEWTON

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
pip uninstall keystone